# Google Cloud SQL Access Control Error

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I cannot access to "Access Control" page in my Google CloudSQL Administration Panel.

I get a page with the "source code" of the tags,

[image: Google Cloud SQL Access Control - Don't Renderer Page]

I have waited 4 days but it still doesn't work.

Does any other person have the same problem?, It's only on my area or in my network?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the Spanish version of the site, this will be resolved soon. In the meantime, you can switch to English by going to the main [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) page, then click on "Configuracion de la cuenta" on the left menu, and set Idioma to English.